# JUnit Mockito: Testing a Static Method and Calling Another Stubbed Static Method Inside Not Working

Tags: junit, mockito, static-functions, mockstatic

```
class A {
   public static int f1() {
      return 1;
   }
   
   public static int f2() {
      return A.f1();
   }
}

class ATest {
   @Test
   void testF2() {
      try (MockedStatic<A> aStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(A.class)) {
         aStatic.when(A::f1).thenReturn(2);
         int ret = A.f2(); // getting 0 here
         assertEquals(ret, 2);
      } catch(Exception e) {
      
      }
   }
}
```

In the testF2 I want to test static function A::f2().

And it internally calls another static function A::f1().

I did stub A::f1() to return 2 using "MockedStatic" and "when" way.

But it's not working, it's returning 0.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

When you mock a class with static methods, all static methods are mocked. If you only want to mock the behavior of only 1 method, you have to add Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS argument to Mockito.mockStatic() as you can see in the following example.

```
 @Test
  void testF2() {
    try (MockedStatic<A> aStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(A.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
      aStatic.when(A::f1).thenReturn(2);
      int ret = A.f2(); // getting 2 here
      Assert.assertEquals(2, ret); // (expected, result)
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
  }
```

This way only the f1 method invocation is mocked but f2 invocation calls the real code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss to specify a mock behavior:

```
class ATest {
  @Test
  void testF2() {
    try (MockedStatic<A> aStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(A.class)) {
        aStatic.when(A::f1).thenReturn(2);
        aStatic.when(A::f2).thenReturn(A.f1()); // <- added this
        int ret = A.f2(); // getting 0 here
        Assertions.assertEquals(ret, 2);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
}
```

by telling the mock what to do when `A.f2()` is invoked, test runs fine.

**Update:**
Mocks do what you tell them, if you don't tell what to do when a method is invoked they do nothing, that's why you have to mock `f2` too.

You want to test `A`, then mock it is not your friend. I normally use a `Mockito.spy()` to partially mock my subject under test .You want to mock `f1` but test `f2`, I don't think `spy` applies here because there is no instance to spy..

I suggest you to rearrange `A` avoiding static methods if possible or using parameters you can mock.

Comment: I tried to keep things simple.

A::f2() may not return exactly A::f1().

But the thing is f1() is called inside f2() and I need to mock that f1() call.


public static int f2() {

     // do some stuffs

      return A.f1();

   }

Comment: Ok, but you still have to tell mock what to do when `f2` is called.

Comment: Maybe you want to spy `A`? I don't know if Mockito provides a way to 'spy' static classes, not surprised if he don't.

Comment: I don't want to mock f2. Want to mock f1() only. And I want to test f2(). Both are static functions of the same class.